# How to generate a form based on a configuration and retrieve all values from it on submit?

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuetifyjs3

When launching my Vue 3 app it asks for a configuration from an external API. This returns an array of

```
interface FieldConfig {
  fieldId: string;
  dataType: 'string' | 'boolean' | 'number';
  defaultValueFunction?: () => Promise<unknown> | unknown;
}
```

Based on those field configurations I want to create a form ( where each `dataType` decides which input to render ) and whenever I click the submit button I want the form to collect all the field values so I can add them as a payload to a POST request body.

Since everything should be reactive and the communication should be bidirectional I'm struggling to create a form with `v-model`s out of nowhere so I started with a basic component rendering the a single input

FormField.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { FieldConfig } from "./FieldConfig.ts";

defineProps<{
  fieldConfiguration: FieldConfig;
  fieldValue: boolean | string | number | null | undefined
}>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "update:modelValue", newValue: boolean | string | number | null | undefined): void;
}>();

function emitNewValue(newValue: boolean | string | number | null | undefined) {
  emit("update:modelValue", newValue);
}
</script>

<template>
  <v-checkbox v-if="fieldConfiguration.dataType === 'boolean'" label="boolean" :model-value="fieldValue" @update:modelValue="emitNewValue" />
  <v-text-field v-else-if="fieldConfiguration.dataType === 'number'" type="number" label="number or null" :model-value="fieldValue" clearable @update:modelValue="emitNewValue" />
  <v-text-field v-else-if="fieldConfiguration.dataType === 'string'" label="string or null" :model-value="fieldValue" clearable @update:modelValue="emitNewValue" />
</template>
```

Now the tricky part: I created a form that must be able to hold all the field values based on the props ( holding the field configurations ). You will see that I created a local ref variable holding all the form values. I initialize the variable inside the `onMounted` hook

CreateForm.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, onMounted } from "vue";
import { FieldConfig } from "./FieldConfig.ts";
import FormField from "./FormField.vue";

const props = defineProps<{
  fieldConfigurations: FieldConfig[]
}>();

const emit = defineEmits<{
  (e: "create", payload: Record<string, unknown>): void;
}>();

const createForm = ref<VForm>();
const payload: [string, unknown][] = ref([]);

onMounted(() => {
  resetForm();
});

function create() {
  let payloadAsRecord: Record<string, unknown> = {};

  payload.value.forEach(([fieldId, fieldValue]) => {
        payloadAsRecord[fieldId] = fieldValue;
  });

  emit("create", payloadAsRecord);
  
  resetForm();
}

function onValueChanged(fieldId: string, newValue: unknown) {
  payload.value = payload.value.map(([currentFieldId, currentFieldValue]) => {
    if(currentFieldId === fieldId) {
        return [currentFieldId, newValue];  
    }
    
    return [currentFieldId, currentFieldValue];
  });
}

/* async */ function resetForm() {
  payload.value = props.fieldConfigurations.map(fieldConfiguration => {
    let initialValue = null;
    
    if(fieldConfiguration.dataType === 'boolean') {
      initialValue = false;
    }
    
    // call async defaultValueFunction if defined
    
    return [fieldConfiguration.fieldId, initialValue];
  });
}
</script>

<template>
    <v-card>
      <v-card-text>
        <v-form ref="createForm">
          <form-field
            v-for="([fieldId, fieldValue], fieldIndex) in payload"
            :key="fieldIndex"
            :fieldConfiguration="fieldConfigurations.find(fieldConfig => fieldConfig.fieldId === fieldId)!"
            :fieldValue="fieldValue"
            @update:modelValue="onValueChanged(fieldId, $event)"
          />
        </v-form>
      </v-card-text>
      <v-card-actions>
        <v-spacer />
        <v-btn @click="create">Submit</v-btn>
      </v-card-actions>
    </v-card>
</template>
```

For testing purposes I consume this form component with the following mock data

```
const fieldConfigurations: Ref<FieldConfig[]> = ref([
  { fieldId: 'field-1', dataType: 'boolean' },
  { fieldId: '2', dataType: 'string', defaultValueFunction: () => 'foo' },
  { fieldId: 'numeric', dataType: 'number', defaultValueFunction: async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    
    return 42;
  }}
]);
```

You can play around with the code [**here**](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

I would like to know if there are any better ways to solve this. I think the component runs into troubles whenever the props change because the `onMounted` hook does not run again.

And maybe I don't even know the local `payload` ref variable because this can be solved "smarter"... I basically want to generate a form based on the field configurations and ask the form for all values whenever I want to submit them.

Comment: Your approach is good and best part is that inputs are dynamically configurable based on the `dataType` property. One suggestion, instead of adding v-if in v-text-field, You can directly assign the `fieldConfiguration.dataType` in `type` and `label` attributes of input.

Comment: yes, I thought about it :) But this is just a small example, there are more inputs e.g. selects to come

Comment: You deleted your last question while I was answering it. Do you still need an answer?